# Get total by type and find out the percentage for every type

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table tbTest:

```
id | q1| q2| q3| q4| UserType
----------------------------------    
1  | 2 | 1 | 3 | 5 | Student    
2  | 5 | 4 | 1 | 3 | Alumni    
3  | 1 | 5 | 1 | 5 | Alumni    
4  | 2 | 1 | 4 | 4 | Student    
5  | 4 | 5 | 3 | 1 | Teacher
```

Now I want to convert it like this(don't need to show this table)

```
UserType | total |
------------------
Alumni   |  25   |    
Student  |  22   |    
Teacher  |  13   |
```

And finally, I want to like this:

```
UserType | percentage|
------------------
Alumni   |   41.67   |    
Student  |   36.67   |     
Teacher  |   21.67   |
```

My attempt:

```
select v.q
    , sum(case when t.userType = 'student' then 1 else 0 end) as student
    , sum(case when t.userType = 'alumni' then 1 else 0 end) as alumni
from tbTest t
cross apply (values ('q1', t.q1), ('q2', t.q2), ('q3', t.q3)) v(q, val)
group by v.q;
```

Comment: sorry I don't understand

Comment: 'select * from tbTest'

Comment: 'select v.q,
       sum(case when t.userType = 'student' then 1 else 0 end) as student,
       sum(case when t.userType = 'alumni' then 1 else 0 end) as alumni
from tbTest t cross apply
     (values ('q1', t.q1), ('q2', t.q2), ('q3', t.q3)) v(q, val)
group by v.q;'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analytic functions to the rescue here.  We can aggregate by `UserType`, take the sum of all quarters, and then divide by the total sum of quarters over all groups to generate the percentages you want.

```
SELECT
    UserType,
    100.0 * SUM(q1 + q2 + q3 + q4) / SUM(SUM(q1 + q2 + q3 + q4)) OVER () AS percentage
FROM tbTest
GROUP BY
    UserType;
```

[image: screen capture of demo link below]

### Demo

**Edit:**

If there be any chance that one of the quarter cells could be `NULL`, you may use `ISNULL()` to replace such values with zero before aggregating:

```
SELECT
    UserType,
    100.0 * SUM(ISNULL(q1, 0) + ISNULL(q2, 0) + ISNULL(q3, 0) + ISNULL(q4, 0)) /
        SUM(SUM(ISNULL(q1, 0) + ISNULL(q2, 0) + ISNULL(q3, 0) + ISNULL(q4, 0)))
        OVER () AS percentage
FROM tbTest
GROUP BY
    UserType;
```

Comment: [Demo2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d92c99473e7f7600c16b21ca386d1ff8)

Comment: @NeloySarothi One workaround might be to use `ISNULL()` to replace such `NULL` values with zero before aggregating.

Comment: Great.  Use `ROUND(num, 2)`.

Comment: After using ROUND(num,2) my problem doesn't solve because it shows other digits as zero(0)  [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=eeedd0a364cec3ec965499731b3b2abe)

Comment: Then use `CAST(41.66666 AS NUMERIC(10,2))`

Comment: yeah now I get the aspected figure